# Is there a `--paranoid` type flag for common, potentially irreversible commands?

Tags: command, options

I'm not aware of any standard flag that is implemented. There are some `git` commands that let you specify a `-n` parameter that will show you what the command is going to do, but doesn't *actually* do it.

Commands that I'm specifically interested in include `rm` and `mv` -- am I out of luck?

Comment: A common problem with scripting is the need to test the script before it is run.  However, because scripts typically have a large number of side effects (e.g., network, filesystem, etc.), it is actually quite difficult to test scripts in an isolated environment and examine the side-effects.  I'm not aware of any good solution to this problem.

Comment: Not really a full answer, but the `--simulate` and `--assume-no` flags of `apt-get` may save your setup some day... Other package managers often provide similar switches. Handy, especially for those who carelessly accept everything `apt-get` is proposing to do.

Answer (score 3):

`rm -i` and `mv -i` forces these commands to ask for user confirmation before performing destructive actions (i.e. mv will only ask for confirmation if overwriting other files, while rm will always ask).

In fact I have this in my .bashrc:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
```

Update: It is important to notice that with those aliases in place, you can use `-f` to revert back to system default of not asking for confirmation (a `-f` after a `-i` overrides it).

Comment: Man, that could be so tedious if you're deleting a directory with hundreds or thousands of files..

Comment: Nice one, is there that type of flag for more commands?

Comment: Not actually @MrDuk, with those aliases in place, if you specify the `-f`, it will ovirride the `-i` as these commands consider the rightmost parameter in this case, so this is actually just setting the default behavior as "ask first" but still allows you to force (i.e., revert back to the system default of not asking) in case you wish.

Answer (score 2):

`mv` and `rm` both have a `-i` option that will prompt before destructive actions... but then again for `rm` every successful action is a destructive action so such an option is mostly useless in my opinion. In the case of `mv`, for interactive use I use `-i` by default and I find it to be an excellent precaution.

`-n` as in the `git` example you have is quite common: for example, `make` supports it. But it's not universal either. Nothing is.